# Run SQL queries

Tags: sql, variables, ms-access-2007

I am very new to using Microsoft Access queries, I want to run a query in SQL like one as follows:

```
    SELECT StudentID FROM tbl_Student WHERE FirstName = Joe;

    StudentIDVariable = resultfromQuery
```

then the out of the query to be used in the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_Purchases WHERE StudentID = StudentIDVariable;
```

Thank you for any help! Not sure where to start with this, could someone give me an example of how this code would work in microsoft access

Comment: [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles) No, they should not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the two tables in a query. The sql would look something like this:

SELECT tbl_Purchases.* FROM tbl_Purchases inner join tbl_Student on tbl_Purchases.StudentID = tbl_Student.StudentID WHERE tbl_Student.FirstName = Joe

The query designer in Access can handle this kind of query quite well. Be advised that if more than one record matches the FirstName field in tbl_Student you will get the purchases records for all of them.

Hope this helps.